# Does this statement `arr[i++] += x;` exhibit undefined behavior?

Tags: c

Is this Undefined Behaviour?

```
arr[i++] += x;       //   [1]

// arr is an array of integer type and x is an integer type variable
// Assumptions - 
// 1. Value of i is a valid index value of array arr and 
//    the result of prefix/postfix increment/decrement of i
//    is also a valid index value of array arr.
// 2. The value of array members and variable x is such that 
//    arithmetic operation (+) does not result in overflow.
```

---

`gcc` and `clang` compiler does not give any warning message on statement `[1]` but if I replace `[1]` with this statement -

```
arr[i++] = arr[i++] + x;     //  [2]
```

they emit a warning message on this statement, which is quite obvious -

`gcc` compiler:

```
warning: operation on ‘i’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
  arr[i++] = arr[i++] + x;
```

`clang` compiler:

```
warning: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'i' [-Wunsequenced]
        arr[i++] = arr[i++] + x;
```

Comment: `arr[i++] += x;` and `arr[i++] = arr[i++] + x;` are not equivalent statements. The Standard guarantees that `arr[i++]` is evaluated only once in the first statement, while `arr[i++]` is evaluated _twice_ in the second statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr[i++] += x;
```

is well-defined; no object is modified more than once between sequence points.  It is effectively equivalent to

```
tmp <- i
arr[tmp] <- arr[tmp] + x;
i <- i + 1
```

with the caveat that the last two updates can occur in any order, even simultaneously.

By contrast,

```
arr[i++] = arr[i++] + x;
```

results in undefined behavior because `i` is modified more than once between sequence points.  Even

```
arr[i++] = arr[i] + x;
```

and

```
arr[i] = arr[i++] + x;
```

result in undefined behavior because `i` is both being updated and used in a value computation between sequence points.

Arithmetic expressions aren't guaranteed to be evaluated left to right, nor are side effects guaranteed to be applied immediately after evaluation; the above expressions can yield more than one result, and as far as the language definition is concerned all those different results are equally correct.

To render those well-defined, separate the update of `i` from the update of `arr[i]`:

```
arr[i] = arr[i] + x;
i++; // or ++i, same result in this context.
```

Or, just use

```
arr[i++] += x;
```

Answer (score 4):

At first glimpse, it seems that the statement exhibit Undefined Behavior but it is **not**.

From c17#6.5.16.2 $4 [emphasis added]

> 3 A compound assignment of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to the simple assignment expression E1 = E1 op (E2), **except that the lvalue E1 is evaluated only once**, and with respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of a compound assignment is a single evaluation. If E1 has an atomic type, compound assignment is a read-modify-write operation with memory_order_seq_cst memory order semantics.115)

Also check **reference<sup>1)</sup>** below.

In this statement, the lvalue `arr[i++]` will be evaluated only once

```
arr[i++] += x;
```

It will be *treated* as

```
arr[i] = arr[i] + x;
i++;
```

Similarly, if prefix increment used, the statement

```
arr[++i] += x;
```

will be *treated* as

```
++i;
arr[i] = arr[i] + x;
```

So, the modification in the value of `i` is not unsequenced to either a different modification in the value of `i` or using the value of `i` for computing `arr[i]`. [**reference<sup>1)</sup>**]

Hence, the statement `arr[i++] += x;` **does not exhibits Undefined Behavior**.
[*Same hold for prefix/postfix decrement if used in the statement `arr[i++] += x;`.*]

Whereas, in the statment `[2]` -

```
arr[i++] = arr[i++] + x;
```

the evaluation of L.H.S. and R.H.S. `i++` are unsequenced: they may be performed in any order (within a single thread of execution, the compiler may interleave the CPU instructions that comprise L.H.S. and R.H.S. `i++` evaluation). If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to another side effect on the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined and, therefore, compiler is giving warning on it.

Note that following statements also exhibits Undefined Behavior

```
arr[i++] += arr[i];
arr[i] += arr[i++];
arr[i] += i++;
arr[++i] += i;
arr[i++] = i;
```

for the same reason explained above.

---

1). Reference:

c17#6.5 $2

> 2 If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the
> same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior
> is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the
> behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.95)

c17#6.5.16 $3

> 3 An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the left operand. An assignment
> expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment,125) but is not an lvalue. The type of
> an assignment expression is the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion. The side
> effect of updating the stored value of the left operand is sequenced after the value computations of
> the left and right operands. The evaluations of the operands are unsequenced.